# What is the connector on this component and is it standardised?

Tags: identification

[image: Phone Camera Connector]

The connector seems to have 30 pins. The inscription reads:

```
P60-B
30 B 16
```

What is the name of the connector on this phone camera? It's the back camera on a Pinephone Pro.

Is it standardised? For example (software support aside) if I search for the name of the connector, will I be able to find other components that I can replace the camera with? For instance, if a component advertises as I2C, then I know I can connect it to circuits that support I2C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connector seems to be a fairly common mezzanine connector, but the signals run over these are not in any way standardized.

It's also highly unlikely that you'll run anything else than a camera link across this - that's too many pins for USB, so this probably carries a parallel camera link directly to the camera-specific peripheral on the central SoC.

And: cameras themselves are specific. So even replacing that camera module for a different one would be challenging and most likely require changes to the operating system of your phone.

Now, the pinephone is essentially an eval board so chances are things *are* documented on the wiki or you can just ask their community.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's a IMX258 according to the wiki.